# For a $3$-by-$3$ matrix, find $A$, $B$ integer $3$-by-$3$ matrices with determinant $\pm 1$ such that $AMB$ is diagonal.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

For a $3$-by-$3$ integer matrix $M$, find $A$, $B$ integer $3$-by-$3$ matrices with determinant $\pm 1$ such that $AMB$ is diagonal.

$\textbf{My Attempt}:$ Given $M$ we want to right-mulitply by an element $A_1 \in GL_3(\mathbb{Z})$ to put $M$ in the form,

$MA_1 = \begin{pmatrix} g_1 & 0 & 0 \\
* & * & * \\
* & * & * \end{pmatrix}$ where $g_1$ is necessarily to the $gcd$ of the top row of $M$.

Assume $$ M = \begin{pmatrix} a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\
g & h & i \end{pmatrix}$$ Then for the $gcd$ of the top row there exists integers, $r, x, y, k \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that, $$ ra + k(xb + y c) = gcd(a,b,c)$$ So my initial attempt for $A_1$ would be to write, $$A_1= \begin{pmatrix} r & * & * \\
kx & * &* \\
ky & * & * \end{pmatrix}$$

I am however very stuck what to do after this step. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Look up *Smith normal form* in linear algebra textbooks.